# How do make an Excel cell reference a particular sheet according to the current date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel spreadsheet for tracking sales with the first page being for totals, then a separate page for each month's sales, which has subtotals on each page.

Can I make the "this month's total" cells on the first page look at the corresponding month's pages' subtotal cells? Currently I have to re-address the formulas at the beginning of each month to point to this month's subtotals. Not a huge hassle obviously, but it would be nice if it just rolled over automagically...

Comment: How are your sheets named? Are they in full month name (January, February, etc) or short form (All are 3 letters: Jan, Feb, etc)?

Comment: Short names. Jan, Feb, Mar etc. All have max 3 letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `INDIRECT` with a combination of `TEXT` and `TODAY`. Let's say that the function you're using currently has the format:

```
=SUM(Jan!A1:A10)
```

You will change it so it becomes:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(TEXT(TODAY(),"mmm")&"!A1:A10"))
```

`TEXT(TODAY(),"mmm")` this gives the short month (`TODAY` gives today's date, `TEXT` converts it).

Then `INDIRECT` turns the short month concatenated to the range to a range for the `SUM` to evaluate.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, and it's nearly there, but not quite. That formula would add up a range on another page, yes? There is already a cell on the other page that adds it up (ie =Jan!C20) and I just need to grab that C20 cell on the months page depending on what month we are currently in

Comment: @Matt Just change it to `=INDIRECT(TEXT(TODAY(),"mmm")&"!C20")` :)

Comment: OK, got it. I used your formula to do the adding up rather than referencing the cell, works fine! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Matt Awesome! ^^ You're welcome

Comment: Both work. Two answers in one, you are good...